# How to convert to Java 8 map grouping by Map<K,V>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have started with Java 8 streams.

The following returns a map of `Map<Long, TradeFileInstance>`

```
Map<Long, List<TradeFileInstance>> configInstanceMap = new HashMap<Long, List<TradeFileInstance>>();
List<TradeFileInstance> tradeFileInstances = tradeFileInstanceRepository.findAll();

configInstanceMap = tradeFileInstances.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(tradeFileInstance ->
                                tradeFileInstance.getTradeFileConfig().getId()));
                        return configInstanceMap;
```

But I need to  return map of `Map<TradeFileConfig, List<TradeFileInstance>>`

We can get TradeFileCongig object by `tradeFileInstance.getTradeFileConfig()` in the above code

Comment: So what prevents you from using `tradeFileInstance.getTradeFileConfig()` in `groupBy`? Does `TradeFileConfig` override `hashCode` and `equals` methods.

Comment: The answer is in the question. Replace `tradeFileInstance.getTradeFileConfig().getId()`, which allows getting the long from the TradeFileInstance, by `tradeFileInstance.getTradeFileConfig()`, which, as you're saying, allows getting the TradeFileConfig.

Answer (score 1):

```
 tradeFileInstances.stream()
                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(TradeFileInstance::getTradeFileConfig));
```

Assuming that `TradeFileConfig` overrides `equals/hashCode`

Comment: Yes it overrides haschode and equals .Error: TradeFileConfig is not a funcitonal interface

Comment: @user1941043 are you sure you use the exact code showed in the answer?

Comment: @Eugene very much doubt!!.